# How to shoot bullets

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

I'm trying to create a browser VR game, I have set up the world, the VR controllers, I have created the fire event but each time I pull the trigger, the bullet that was fired before disappears. How do I make the bullets "stay" in the scene and keep moving, while I fire new ones?

I'm following this example https://threejs.org/examples/#webvr_ballshooter but it's not exactly what I need

```
        var geometry_bullet = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry( radius, 2 );
        var bullet1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_bullet, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x2661b9 } ) );
        bullet1.userData.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
        bullet1.userData.velocity.x = 10;
        bullet1.userData.velocity.y = 10;
        bullet1.userData.velocity.z = 10;

        var bullet2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_bullet, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xee2f2f } ) );
        bullet2.userData.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
        bullet2.userData.velocity.x = 1;
        bullet2.userData.velocity.y = 1;
        bullet2.userData.velocity.z = 1;


   ...



  function handleController( controller ) {

  if ( controller1.userData.isSelecting ) {

               bullet1.position.set(controller1.position.x   , controller1.position.y + 0.018 , controller1.position.z );
               bullet1.userData.velocity.x = 0;
               bullet1.userData.velocity.y = 10;
               bullet1.userData.velocity.z = 10;
               bullet1.userData.velocity.applyQuaternion( controller1.quaternion );


            }

 if ( controller2.userData.isSelecting ) {

                bullet2.position.set(controller2.position.x  , controller2.position.y + 0.018 , controller2.position.z );
                bullet2.userData.velocity.x = 0;
                bullet2.userData.velocity.y = 10;
                bullet2.userData.velocity.z = 10;
                 bullet2.userData.velocity.applyQuaternion( controller2.quaternion );


            }

        } ...


function render() { ... 

handleController( controller1 );
handleController( controller2 ); ...

bullet1.position.x -= bullet1.userData.velocity.x *  delta;
bullet1.position.y -= bullet1.userData.velocity.y *  delta;
bullet1.position.z -= bullet1.userData.velocity.z *  delta;
scene.add(bullet1);


bullet2.position.x -= bullet2.userData.velocity.x *  delta;
bullet2.position.y -= bullet2.userData.velocity.y *  delta;
bullet2.position.z -= bullet2.userData.velocity.z *  delta;
scene.add(bullet2);

 ...
 renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
       }
```

Comment: How did you create those bullets? Could create a working example for us we can help you?

Comment: Think of a solution that does not rely on bullets named bullet1 to bulletN. ( array of bullet objects and functions?, bullet class? ) You should be able to support infinite bullets if you'd want to, without having to write the variable name bullet112187454212177521. There's probably a part of your code that overwrites bullet1 with bullet2, but it's not shown here and we'd rather fix the underlying problem.

Comment: @hurricane I have added the code that creates the bullet1 and bullet2 (basically they're just two spheres), but I think I'm gonna have to delete that because I've found out they have to be rigidbody.